# Better approach for one way encryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes

We have requirement of one way encryption. Can any one suggest a better approach between

**AES , DSA and Dygest-salt** enctyption approach?

I think Dygest-salt is for one way and other are for two-way but not sure which is more secure for use. It would be better if someone can point out the **performace comparison** between these two. Feel free to suggest another algorithm (specific for one way).

Answer (score 5):

The term "one-way encryption" is misleading.

[AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is an example for a **symmetric encryption algorithm** (a [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher), to be precise). Whoever has the key to encrypt, also can decrypt. You normally use a block cipher not by itself, but with a [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation).

[DSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) is not an encryption algorithm at all. It is a **signature algorithm** (or actually a bundle of three algorithms: key generation, signature, verification), where I can sign a piece of data with my private key, and everyone can check the signature with the corresponding public key. I also need a hash function applied on my data before the signing.

A (cryptographic) **hash algorithm** (also called (cryptographic) **message digest**) is normally a key-less function, and reduces (more or less) arbitrarily sized data to a fixed-size hash, such that it should be hard to find two different inputs which result in the same hash (and usually some more properties). This is a kind of **one-way function**.

For password storage, we don't use encryption, but a form of hashing, which includes a random **salt**, so that identical passwords with different salts give different results. The salt itself is stored with the hash, so it is available for checking the password later. (It could be that this is what you are referring to as **Digest-Salt**.)
[Also, you should not use a normal *fast* hash function, but a slow one.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-makes-a-hash-function-good-for-password-hashing)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this article on storing passwords securely](http://throwingfire.com/storing-passwords-securely).  (For those who don't want to click the link, check out PBKDF2 and bcrypt.)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for 'one-way' encryption. You're looking for performance characteristics. and you're calling out 2 implementations and a concept (Dygest-salt is conceptual)

You need to ask the following questions:

1. Do you ever want to decrypt it
2. do you care about duplication

plain encryption is the turning of a known piece of data into an equivalent set of data that can be decrpyted using the key that was used for the original encryption. Size(in) == Size(out)

Hashing is the concept of reducing a large corpus of text into a small string that can more easily be compared than the original text. In general this means that the source data is much larger than the hash data.

cryptographically, hashing is the reduction of a large corpus of text into a small string where changes in the content cause significantly different hashes, making it difficult to produce two sources which result in the same hash.

Hashing should be 'faster' than full encryption because we do not ultimately care about the content - in fact you can use AES in a [hashing mode](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/aes-hash/aeshash.pdf), which leaves you with the same characteristics, but the end product is a hash, rather than an encrpytion.

If you never want to obtain the plain-text, then you should always use a hash function - they're designed for relatively rapid operation - they're not free, but that is the point.

Comment: I said one way. Doesn't that implicitely points out my need of not decrypting it?

Comment: Yes, but your question alludes to the use of two-way algorithms